# Converting string to datetime object in Python (GAE)?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I'm very new to Python, but I need to migrate a project from PHP to Python (running in GAE environment) and I need to move all data from one database to GAE's one.
The chellenge is to write data strings into datetime objects.
Dates are stored as strings, which where created using PHP's pattern "l dS of F Y ( h:i:s A )"
So every date looks like this:
Sunday 31st of July 2005 ( 02:05:50 PM )

I've looked into Python documentation on that, and I can see that **datetime.strptime** can do the job, but...
It has no parameter for "th", "rd", and "st" endings. And may have some other issues as well.

What could you advise me?
I can use RegExp and remove all unneccessary crap, or is there any way to create a datetime object from such a string directly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil) with GAE, then

```
In [70]: import dateutil.parser as parser
In [71]: parser.parse('Sunday 31st of July 2005 ( 02:05:50 PM )',fuzzy=True)
Out[71]: datetime.datetime(2005, 7, 31, 14, 5, 50)
```

Otherwise, you'll have to rely on `re` to manipulate the date string into a format `strptime` can parse.

```
In [89]: datetime.datetime.strptime(re.sub(r'\w+ (\d+)\w+ of(.+)\s+\( (.+) \)',r'\1 \2 \3','Sunday 31st of July 2005 ( 02:05:50 PM )'),'%d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p')
Out[89]: datetime.datetime(2005, 7, 31, 14, 5, 50)
```

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately GAE's SDK doesn't have dateutil.parser module.
And when I try your second example it triggers
comment.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(re.sub(r'\w+ (\d+)\w+ of(.+)\s+\( (.+) \)',r'\1 \2 \3', remove_html_tags(_date)),'%d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: ___________

Comment: @momijigari: Please post `repr(remove_html_tags(_date))`.

Comment: @momijigari: Also there should be a way to [install dateutil with GAE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631035/python-tzinfo-and-daylight-time). Unfortunately, the link does not show how, but it does imply it is possible.

Comment: thank you for your help! I just downloaded the dateutil module and put it into the same directory as me app.yaml is — and your first code worked like a charm! Thanks.